# Storing floats as varchars in sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, floating-point, varchar

I'm working on a project that involves decimal point numbers (floats). Now my question is, do you think it would be a good idea to just store the floats as strings in varchar fields, and then convert them when I want to perform math on them?

Or should I store them into REAL fields? (which is what I'm doing right now).

I'd really just like some opinions on the subject and maybe some pros and cons.

Comment: I find it really hard to understand why anyone would ever store anything other than a string as a string. Unless maybe you're trying to implement an untyped column, at least.

Comment: Soliciting opinions is often frowned upon since it merely encourages debate rather than substantive answers. But why do you want to convert the floats in the first place? You used the SQLite tag, are you referring to storing them in a database? If so the column type doesn't always matter since SQLite uses "type affinity"...

Comment: i don't see any pros for using a varchar. you'll send hours in conversions, loose precision every time (as i assume you'll save the varchar in base 10), and use more space. generally speaking, convert as little as possible, and only at the last possible moment (typically for display)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general case, you should store numbers as numbers.
It's faster, uses less space, avoids rounding errors, and prevents your code from showing up on The Daily WTF.

There might be specific cases where storing numbers as text would make sense due to some very unusual constraints of your project, with without telling us about your project, you're asking us to invent such constraints.

So, there a no pros.